# Problems with Quickbooks Online API creating an app

Tags: api, quickbooks-online

Trying to create a QuickBooks Online App.

The developer.Intuit.com screens tells me that it must verify my email.  It sends an email, I click on the Verify button, it says that the email is verifiied and nothing else.

If I try again to create the App it again says that the verfiy email has already been sent.

How can I get passed this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is wrong here. Consider mailing the support of intuit.com, we can't help you with such problems.

Answer (score -1):

After doing email verification, paste the following link in your browser. It will work fine

https://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/IA

or

Follow the standard navigation

[image]

Thanks

Comment: After about 3 attempts I was actually able to proceed without it asking to verify my email.  It was almost like there was a delay in the verification process.

The when I went to log into QBO it would not let me.  Asked if I wanted a subscription (which I already had for years).  Happened on multiple browsers, multiple machines. With no way out of it. Could not switch to other companies, etc.

We even support other customers with QBO now cannot even log into their QBO.